# Where are th NLTK api doc or where do I find all available constructors of FreqDist

Tags: nltk, doc

I'm trying to find all available constructors to NLTK's FreqDist class. It seems like http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.probability.FreqDist ist the official api documentation but there should be at least one constructor that takes an NLTK text object as an argument.

I'm most likely just blind :(

Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: NLTK's `nltk.probability.FreqDist` is a subclass of native `collection.Counter` which is a subclass of native python dictionary. So you **CANNOT** pass in an NLTK text into a FreqDist constructor but you can pass in a list of strings.

Comment: You need to do something like `from itertools import chain` then `from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize` and then `FreqDist(chain(*[[word for word in word_tokenize(sent)] for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]))`

Comment: I cannot?                                                                                                          
>>> print(FreqDist(nltk.Text(['this','is','some','text'])))                                                          
<FreqDist with 4 samples and 4 outcomes>

Comment: Sorry, i'm moving around for today. I'll try to reply tomorrow if no one else replies.